# Localizable push notifications

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, push-notification, mpns

I want to localizate a Tile and Content for Toast push notification.
Can I get localizated string from application when I getting a new push notification? (**NOT in server side**)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to run any code in response to a notification being received by the phone (like you can on other platforms).

If you want to localize the contents of a notification it ***MUST*** be done on the server side.